# How to transform an array field into a value equaling its maximum?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql, aggregation-framework, mongodb-indexes

```
{
   name: "use_name",
   grades: [
     {class: "math": grade: 100},
     {class: "english": grade: 90}
   ]
}
```

How do I write an aggregation pipeline to output:

```
{
   name: "use_name",
   grades: {class: "math": grade: 100},
   
}
```

The grades field has been reduced to the element where its grade property is the maximum of all elements.

The requirements, the aggregation pipeline cannot have `$unwind` or `$group` because it cannot have a stage where the stage needs to receive all incoming documents before outputting to the next stage, potentially exceeding the 100mb limit. And it must be fast.

Comment: `$reduce` probably does what you're looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this one is faster:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      grades: {
        $first: {
          $sortArray: {
            input: "$grades",
            sortBy: { grade: -1 }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KtxCPUjxMCj)

or this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      grades: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$grades",
          cond: { $eq: [ "$$this.grade", { $max: "$grades.grade" } ] }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `$$value` in `$reduce` until you find the max.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      grades: {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$grades",
          "initialValue": null,
          "in": {
            "$cond": {
              "if": {
                $or: [
                  {
                    $eq: [
                      null,
                      "$$value"
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    $gt: [
                      "$$this.grade",
                      "$$value.grade"
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              "then": "$$this",
              "else": "$$value"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7ZJff-8HEeI)